# Ensuring that polygons rather than multipatch features are created by ArcGIS KML To Layer tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, kmz, multipatch, arcgis-10.6

Today I received a 10m reference grid as part of a KMZ file and when I converted it to a file geodatabase feature class using the KML To Layer tool from ArcGIS Desktop 10.6 the features created had a geometry type of multipatch, instead of the polygons that I was expecting.

From [Converting multipatch layer into polygon layer using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232409) I know that an ArcGIS 3D Analyst license would enable me to convert the multipatches to polygons using the MultiPatch Footprint tool, but I do not have that extension licensed.

Surprisingly, a second KMZ file from the same source with what appeared to be the same reference grid, converted to two feature classes (one polygon and the other multipatch).

What triggers the KML To Layer tool to create multipatch features, and can that trigger be redirected to create polygons instead or as well?

Comment: Its the data inside the KMZ. (I dont recall which 'type' of data does what.) - but the short answer is there is no setting on the tool or arcgis. Output polygons vs multipatch is 100% based on the data inside the KMZ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [commented by @KHibma](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271072/ensuring-that-polygons-rather-than-multipatch-features-are-created-by-arcgis-kml#comment431716_271072):

> Its the data inside the KMZ. (I dont recall which 'type' of data does
>   what.) - but the short answer is there is no setting on the tool or
>   arcgis. Output polygons vs multipatch is 100% based on the data inside
>   the KMZ.